# Windows 7 not searching in non-indexed folders

Tags: windows-7, desktop-search, file-search

I am simply not able to use the Windows 7 search box to find files in the current directory.

The following are my settings:

- I have currently configured Windows Indexing only to search in my "Start Menu".
- I am also using primarily a non-Administrator account.
- In the folder search options, I have set it up as "in non-indexed folders search file names only".
- I've also checked that the Windows Search Service is running.

Comment: In Explorer, you are given the option to search non-indexed locations, but you have this disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that when I navigated to the directory via the drive path (C:..), I was able to get file search results. My previous efforts were using the 'Libraries' virtual folder.

After a lot of googling, it was Bing that ironically gave me a decent result:
[Search doesn't work for non-indexed locations in Libraries](http://www.windows7taskforce.com/view/3121)

So it looks like it's a bug !

Comment: "The community Taskforce initiative has now come to a close." too bad they closed it. You can accept you own answer, you get no reps but it will make it easier for others to find the answer.